# Behavior on scale often is not working

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to have an application, where always when new image is loaded, it is appeared by scaling from 0 size to default size. This behavior is often not working. In this image I am also using animation for bouncing when mouse enters to image. Is it possible, that this two animations are not loving themselves and that is, why scaling up is often not working?

I am using Linux Mint 13, Qt 5.3

Here is my Image element:

```
Image {
        id: pic1
        width: appWindow.height*0.4
        height: appWindow.height*0.4
        smooth: { enabled = true
            pic1MouseArea.containsMouse
        }
        states: [ "mouseIn", "mouseOut" ]
        state: "mouseOut"

        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: "*"
                to: "mouseIn"
                NumberAnimation {
                    target: pic1
                    properties: "scale"
                    from: 0.95
                    to: 1
                    duration: 400
                    easing.type: Easing.OutBounce
                }
            }
        ]
        scale: {
            status === Image.Ready ? 1 : 0
        }
        Behavior on scale {
            NumberAnimation{
                from: 0
                to: 1
                duration: 1000
                easing.type: Easing.OutBounce
            }
        }
        MouseArea{
            id: pic1MouseArea
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            onContainsMouseChanged: {
                pic1.state = containsMouse ? "mouseIn" : "mouseOut"
            }
            onClicked: {    
                    MyScript.getRandomFile()   
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read this [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#states-prop). The `states` property must be defined as `list<State>`, not as an array of strings. Also, the `State` element defines some state when a property or set of properties changes from default configuration. In your example states define nothing. Read more about [`State`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-statemachine-state.html) type.

Finally, here is a small example to help you getting on:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true
    Image {
        id: img
        source: "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        opacity: 1
        state: "mouseOut"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "mouseIn"
                PropertyChanges { target: img; opacity: 0 }
            },
            State {
                name: "mouseOut"
                PropertyChanges { target: img; opacity: 1 }
            }
        ]
        transitions: Transition {
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: img
                property: "opacity"
                easing.type: Easing.InCirc
                duration: 1000
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: img.state = "mouseIn"
            onExited: img.state = "mouseOut"
        }
    }
}
```

Sure, you can replace `transitions` with `Behavior`, if you need exactly this functionality, as shown below:

```
Behavior on opacity {
    PropertyAnimation {
        duration: 1000
        easing.type: Easing.InCirc
    }
}
```